# Can an eclipse plugin modify the existing perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin and need to make changes to the existing layout. It seems that this is possible by having the plugin define an entirely new perspective for the plugin. But is there a way to simple detect the existing perspective and make changes to it directly?

Comment: You can extend an existing perspective if you know its id, but this is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a given plugin can extend an existing perspective. You just need the perspective ID.

Here is the reference doc for perspective extensions
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html

This tutorial covers perspectives and their extension (at the end)

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html